# ag-grid-react agDateCellEditor defaulting to text-input instead of date-input

Tags: ag-grid-react

Inside ag-grid-community.js I see that agDateCellEditor is not present. If I'm not mistaken the date cell editor is available w/o enterprise?

I have tried setting up cellEditor: 'agDateCellEditor' and cellDataType: 'date' and the cell still responds with the default text-input.

Is there something simple that can be called to convert the input to a date or a plugin?

Thanks!

-- Additional Notes:

Yes, I am passing the date value as a string so I tried cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor' at the column level as suggested by "Ahmet Firat Keler" and the grid cell still renders as a text input.
example of date string '2023-01-01'

Note: The grid column definitions are stored on a db table, I use a query and convert to JSON and populate the grid definitions.
Below is a JSON stringified console.log output of a column definition.

```json
{"field":"START_DATE",
 "headerName":"Start Date",
 "flex":1,
 "hide":"false",
 "cellEditor":"agDateStringCellEditor"
}
```

I tried also to set cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor' as a default column definition just to be sure and again still a text input vs. a date input. (not database driven)

```json
const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
        editable: true,
        sortable: true,
        wrapHeaderText: true,
        autoHeaderHeight: true,
        cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor'
    };
}, []);
```

package.json w/ ag-grid info entries

```json
"ag-grid-community": "^29.3.5",
"ag-grid-react": "^29.1.0",
```

Just to make double sure I was not doing something very wrong, I tried agSelectCellEditor on both the Default Column Definition and at the cell level and the select input rendered as you would expect. So I don't appear to be doing anything out of the ordinary.

```
AG Grid: Could not find 'agDateStringCellEditor' component. It was configured as "cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor'" but it wasn't found in the list of registered components.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date field is a string, e.x. '2023-07-19', I suggest you to use 'agDateStringCellEditor' as cell editor

```
{
  headerName: 'Date as String Editor',
  field: 'dateString',
  cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor',
},
```

and if it is a Date object like, new Date(2023, 6, 19), you can prefer 'agDateCellEditor' as cell editor

```
{
  headerName: 'Date Editor',
  field: 'date',
  valueFormatter: (params) => {
    if (!params.value) {
      return '';
    }
    const month = params.value.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = params.value.getDate();
    return `${params.value.getFullYear()}-${
      month < 10 ? '0' + month : month
      }-${day < 10 ? '0' + day : day}`;
  },
  cellEditor: 'agDateCellEditor',
},
```

Read more on https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/provided-cell-editors/#date-cell-editor

Answer (score 0):

I searched both ag-grid-community and ag-grid-react modules for the string "agDateStringCellEditor" and found no matching records. Strange because I see documentation that says it's a legit cell editor.

I ended up creating an onClick event that will grab the input id so I can change it from text to date. It does the trick. Still would like to know why agDateStringCellEditor isn't working for me.

work-around

```
        onCellClicked: (event) => {
            if(event.colDef.cellDataType === 'date'){
                var regex = /ag-[0-9].*?-input/;
                var str = event.event.srcElement.innerHTML;
                var result = regex.exec(str);
                if(Array.isArray(result)){
                    var eID = result[0];
                    console.log(document.getElementById(eID));
                    document.getElementById(eID).type = 'date';         
                }
            }
        
        }
```